# Firefox 3 window focus and blur

Tags: javascript, firefox, focus

$(window).blur(function(){
        windowFocus = false;
    }).focus(function(){
        windowFocus = true;
    });

The problem is that in firefox 3, when I create a new tab, it does not lose windowFocus. Where as in ff2, ie7 it does lose. In ff3 it only loses window focus when i select another program.

Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach to the events on `document` instead:

```
$(document).blur(function(){
        windowFocus = false;
}).focus(function(){
        windowFocus = true;
});
```

...FWIW, this appears to have been fixed in FF3.5.

Comment: will this work for ie6/7/8 and ff2? or do i need to write it as a  hack?

Comment: No, but you can probably get away with just wiring up both (since the document can't have focus without the window having focus): $(window, document)...

Comment: @Shog9: that will search for the window object in the document object, the comma only works in string selectors for specifying multiple selectors. Try this instead: $(window).add(document)...

Comment: @Pim Jager: ah, of course... I've made that mistake a few times, sad to say! $([window, document]) should also work.