# How to fix v-align styling for imgs with different sizes in Vue.js transition-group?

Tags: css, animation, vue.js, transition

I prepared example of image slider what I need. 
I encounter with styling issue when using images with various dimensions. When element leaving the array, its location is set as absolute value, what is necessary for smooth transition, tho, but the image is also moved up.

I would like to have nice vertical align into middle even leave or enter the array, but could not get on any way.

Another issue, what I would like to solve is when left the window and then went back after a while. The animation running all cycles at once to reach current state instead just stop animation and run after. Maybe it is my responsibility, but browsers doesn't offer nice event to catch blur window or am I wrong?
[According to this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647308/cross-browser-detect-blur-event-on-window/30383198#30383198)

Thank you for any ideas.

```js
let numbers = [{key:1},{key:2},{key:3},{key:4},{key:5},{key:6},{key:7}]
 
 let images = [
  { key:1,
    src:"http://lorempixel.com/50/100/sports/"},
  { key:2,
    src:"http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/"},
  { key:3,
    src:"http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/"},
  { key:4,
    src:"http://lorempixel.com/20/30/sports/"},
  { key:5,
    src:"http://lorempixel.com/80/20/sports/"},
  { key:6,
    src:"http://lorempixel.com/20/80/sports/"},
  { key:7,
    src:"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/"}
 ]
 
 new Vue({
  el: '#rotator',
  data: {
    items: images,
    lastKey: 7,
    direction: false
  },
  mounted () {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (this.direction) { this.prevr() } else { this.nextr() }
    }, 1000)
  },
  methods: {
    nextr () {
     let it = this.items.shift()
      it.key = ++this.lastKey
      this.items.push(it)
    },
    prevr () {
     let it = this.items.pop()
      it.key = ++this.lastKey
      this.items.unshift(it)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.litem {
  transition: all 1s;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
.innerDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.list-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(40px);
}
.list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-40px);
}
.list-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>

<div id="rotator">
  
  <button @click="direction = !direction">
      change direction
  </button>
  
  <transition-group 
    name="list" 
    tag="div" 
    class="container">
    
      <div 
        v-for="item in items"            
        :key="item.key" class="litem">
        <!-- 
          <div 
            class='innerDiv'>
              {{ item.key }}
          </div> 
        -->
        <div class='innerDiv'>
          <img :src='item.src'>
        </div>
    </div>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tooks a while but on the end I think that I have got better result for sliding animation with changing direction feature.

One annoying think is when I swithing the sliding direction so animation is for a 'microsecond' changed to next state and than return to correct one, after it the animation continue as expected. It is happening only in one direction and I don't know how to fix it. Also last box behave differently too only once. No clue at all.

So just 98% solution :-)

```js
let images = [
  {key:1, domKey:1, src:"http://lorempixel.com/50/100/sports/"  },
  {key:2, domKey:2, src:"http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/"   },
  {key:3, domKey:3, src:"http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/"  },
  {key:4, domKey:4, src:"http://lorempixel.com/20/30/sports/"   },
  {key:5, domKey:5, src:"http://lorempixel.com/80/20/sports/"   },
  {key:6, domKey:6, src:"http://lorempixel.com/20/80/sports/"   },
  {key:7, domKey:7, src:"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/" }
]

let setPositionRelative = el => el.style.position = "relative"

new Vue({
  el: '#rotator',
  data: {
    items: images,
    lastKey: 7,
    direction: true,
    changeDirectionRequest: false
  },
  mounted () {
   Array.from(this.$el.querySelectorAll("div[data-key]")).map(setPositionRelative)
    setInterval(() => {
      if(this.changeDirectionRequest) {
        this.changeDirectionRequest = false
        this.direction = !this.direction
        if (this.direction) 
         Array.from(this.$el.querySelectorAll("div[data-key]")).map(setPositionRelative)
        else 
         Array.from(this.$el.querySelectorAll("div[data-key]")).map(el => el.style.position = "")
      } 
      if (this.direction) this.prevr() 
      else this.nextr()
    }, 1000)
  },
  methods: {
    nextr () {
      let it = this.items.shift()
      it.key = ++this.lastKey
      this.items.push(it)
    },
    prevr () {
     let it = this.items.pop()
      it.key = ++this.lastKey
      this.items.unshift(it)
      setPositionRelative(this.$el.querySelector("div[data-domkey='"+it.domKey+"']"))
    }
 }
})
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.innerDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: auto; 
  height: auto; 

  display:-moz-box; 
  -moz-box-pack:center; 
  -moz-box-align:center; 

  display:-webkit-box; 
  -webkit-box-pack:center; 
  -webkit-box-align:center; 

  display:box; 
  box-pack:center; 
  box-align:center;
}
.litem {
  transition: all 1s;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.list2-enter, .list-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(40px);
}
.list2-leave-to, .list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-40px);
}
.list-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>

<div id="rotator">
  <button @click="changeDirectionRequest = true">change direction</button>
  <transition-group name="list" tag="div" class="container">
    <div   v-for="item in items" 
          :key="item.key" 
          :data-domkey="item.domKey" 
          class="litem">
          
       <div class='innerDiv'>
          <img :src='item.src'>
        </div>
    </div>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```