# How can I catch the click outside the browser - Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

For my project, I need to catch all the click outside the browser in Javascript. Is there a way to do that ? For example by asking the user the right access ?
I need a function like "onclick" that works even outside the browser.

Comment: No, this is not possible (at least I hope it's not). You might be able to detect if a user is no longer focused on the browser?

Comment: Are you trying to catch click event in outside browser such as windows desktop through JS? If so, it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

There are various approaches for [detecting when the focus moves out of the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647308/cross-browser-detect-blur-event-on-window) which would be a side effect of clicking outside the window if the window currently has focus.

Explicitly detecting clicks outside the page is not possible. It would be a security problem if a web page could monitor how the user interacts with other applications.

Comment: What about downloading an extension? If I ask the user to download an extension, can I access the system click?

Answer (score -4):

To detect click outside element with JavaScript, we can use the element’s contains method.

For instance, we write

```
const specifiedElement = document.getElementById("a");

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const isClickInside = specifiedElement.contains(event.target);

  if (!isClickInside) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

to select the element we want to check with getElemebntById.

Then we add a click listener for the whole page with document.addEventListener.

In the callback, we call specifiedElement.contains with event.target to check if we clicked inside the a element.

If it’s false, then we clicked outside of it.

Comment: The question said **browser** not element. That will only detect clicks inside the viewport.

Answer (score -4):

javascript detect click outside of element

```
var ignoreClickOnMeElement = document.getElementById('someElementID');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var isClickInsideElement = ignoreClickOnMeElement.contains(event.target);
    if (!isClickInsideElement) {
        //Do something click is outside specified element
    }
});
```

click outside javascript

```
// Vanilla js
var ignoreMe = document.getElementById("ignoreMe");
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
    if (event.target != ignoreMe && event.target.parentNode != ignoreMe){
    // Place your output
    }
});
```

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/javascript+detect+click+outside+of+element

Comment: The question **still** says **browser** not element. That will  also only detect clicks inside the viewport.